# How to draw a base glyph with one color and its attached diacritic with another one?

Tags: c#, winapi, unicode, fonts, gdi+

MS Word has this capability in its Hebrew and Arabic versions. I would like to achieve this in a windows desktop application, using .Net (may be with win-api calls).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add accent marks with custom colors in .Net's RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016965/add-accent-marks-with-custom-colors-in-nets-richtextbox)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the link provided by Otaku [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016965/add-accent-marks-with-custom-colors-in-nets-richtextbox), current rich text edit controls can not handle this (unless you go for the hack OP in that Q did, which did not seem like a very good solution).

You could write code to do this manually yourself, ditching the text edit control completely, but that would probably mean a lot of work. It took Microsoft years to get support for combining diacritics working properly in MSWord. I would search for open source software that has this capability, and look at how other developers have done it. It might be hard to find, though, and you would likely have to step outside .NET-land. Maybe OpenOffice can do this?

[This](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2003-m12/0379.html) discussion might also be of help.

I am afraid that you will find, though, that you'll have to manually parse the Unicode and assign colors to the correct glyphs. If you want to be complete, that is one heck of a job.